# Animating transform CSS in IE not working as expected

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, transform

I have a CSS animation that I am using on my site to animate an arrow back and forth. It is working fine on every browser except for IE where there is a weird glitch where the arrow's Y position is changing even though it shouldn't be.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('img.next').addClass('animated');
  });
});
```

```css
.arrow-cont {
  height:100%;
  width:130px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img.next {
  width:30px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:20px;
  animation-duration:1.5s;
  animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
  transition:0.5s all ease-in-out;
}
  img.next.animated {
    animation-name:next;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  }

@keyframes next {
    from { transform:translate(0px, -50%); }
    65%  { transform:translate(10px, -50%); }
    to   { transform:translate(0px, -50%); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow-cont">
<img class="next" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Arrow_Blue_Right_001.svg/768px-Arrow_Blue_Right_001.svg.png" />
</div>


<button>Animate</button>
```

Comment: what version of IE?

Comment: @TemaniAfif IE11

Comment: You could try adding the IE prefix for transform. so as well as the regular transform code you have you would add the ms version as follows: -ms-transform: translate(0px, -50%); etc. like in the example here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform

Comment: can't reproduce your problem on my side (using IE 11.1.17134.0 version), please check your IE version, and can you tell us when you found the arrow's Y position is changing

Comment: @Dillion 11.0.9600.19129 [Here's a screen capture](http://sendvid.com/xod5kb50) that shows what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `translateX` & `translateY` properties separately.

Also, I'm not sure why you set `transition:0.5s all ease-in-out`, because nothing is being transitioned. So I removed this.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('img.next').addClass('animated');
  });
});
```

```css
.arrow-cont {
  height: 100%;
  width: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img.next {
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0px);
}

img.next.animated {
  animation-name: next;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes next {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0px);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(10px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow-cont">
  <img class="next" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Arrow_Blue_Right_001.svg/768px-Arrow_Blue_Right_001.svg.png" />
</div>


<button>Animate</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to upgrade the IE 11 Browser version. Because, I didn't find the IE 11.0.9600.19129 version package, I just test your code on IE 11.0.9600.19155 and IE 11.1.17134.0 version, they all works well. So, you could try to use these versions, or upgrade to the latest version.

[image]